# How to protect user credentials (persisted in Neo4J) in JavaScript client code?

Tags: javascript, authentication, neo4j, passwords, password-protection

I am using Neo4J REST-services and passing encrypted username and password as a part of authentication header. But any other person will have access to my username and password as it is in javascript file.

Any suggestion on how can I protect my Neo4J credentials.

Comment: `any other person will have access to my username and password as it is in javascript file` could you elaborate on that? Post some code, please.

Answer (score 1):

As you would do with any other cred, you would store it externally in a config server or environment variable.

That's how all cloud PaaS solutions do it too. So it will only be visible to your process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only JavaScript client without any your own backend there is no way to hide them.